# MVC 3 Web API Routing Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm fighting issues with routing in an MVC 3 Web API.  It seems like it should be pretty simple, but I'm not making any headway.

My error is:

```
  <Error>
     <Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
       <MessageDetail>
           The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Boolean NewViolationsPublished(Int32)' in 'BPA.API.Controllers.CacheManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
       </MessageDetail>
   </Error>
```

My RegisterRoutes is such:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "NukeAllItemsFromCache",
              routeTemplate: "api/CacheManagement/NukeAllItemsFromCache");


            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "ControllerAndAction",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
             );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "ControllerAndActionAndId",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
              constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
             );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerAndId",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
          constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
            );
        }
```

And my controller is (i took out the code for ease of reading):

```
 public class CacheManagementController : ApiController
    {
        public CacheManagementController()        

        [HttpGet]
        public bool NewViolationsPublished(int id)

        [HttpGet]
        public bool IsCached(CachedItemLabels label, int clientId)

        [HttpGet]
        public void RemoveItemFromCache(int clientId, CachedItemLabels cacheLabel, string test)

        [HttpGet]
        public string NukeAllItemsFromCache()    
    }
```

**I get the error when I try to call:**

```
http://localhost/api/CacheManagement/NukeAllItemsFromCache
```

TIA

Comment: Have you tried moving your route to the bottom and loading the defaults first?

Comment: I just moved the NukeAllItemsFromCache route to the bottom of the RegisterRoutes method and got the same error.

Comment: And why aren't you just using the default route of {controller}/{action} to hit it? (Sorry just trying to understand the logic here)    ALSO you are using clientId for RemoveItemFromCache with some additional parameters but your route states it is id, are you able to hit any of your other routes?

Comment: @kadumel I've tried every variant of the routes to get this to work.  Will update in a moment w/ routes explicit to the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're defining your routes in the right place? Web API routes should be configured using System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute (normally in a WebApiConfig.cs file in App_Start), as shown on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api, which is different from the route configuration used by vanilla MVC.

I think you may just be hitting the default Web API route, which is api/{controller}/{id}, with ID optional. The action is determined by the HTTP verb, which in this case is GET, and all of your methods match that by virtue of the [HttpGet].

Edit: example

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalModifiers.ApplyGlobalConfiguration(this, true);
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "action-specific",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: You may be on to something.  Still have research to do, but is WebApiConfig.cs for MVC 3 or just 4? In my Global.asax > Application_Start() I've got RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); that takes me to RouteConfig.cs (not WebApiConfig) w/ some route definitions.

Comment: I'm not sure as I've only used MVC 4. I'll edit the answer with an example from a working Web API site.

Comment: This ultimately lead me to the solution.  I was updating the routes in the Global.asax > RegisterRoutes method as opposed to the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method.  Hence when I updated the routes in the asax method, nothing was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I beleave your problem is in this route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ControllerAndActionAndId",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
  constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);
```

You specify `id` as an optional parameter and at the same time constrain it to actually be a non-nullable number. If `/api/CacheManagement/NukeAllItemsFromCache` is an exception, then add additional route for it, otherwise ease a constraint to something like `@"^\d*$"` if possible.

Comment: But the controller and action route right above it specifies what to do if there is no integer passed through?

Comment: I removed both lines that had 'constraints' entries and the error changed to: 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Boolean NewViolationsPublished(Int32)' in 'xxx.Controllers.CacheManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the default action for the route you configured:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "NukeAllItemsFromCache",
          routeTemplate: "api/CacheManagement/NukeAllItemsFromCache");
```

should be

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "NukeAllItemsFromCache",
          routeTemplate: "api/CacheManagement/NukeAllItemsFromCache",
          defaults: new { action = "NukeAllItemsFromCache" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to put parameter id as nullable like:

```
[HttpGet]
public bool NewViolationsPublished(int? id)
```

or

```
    [HttpGet]
    public bool NewViolationsPublished(Nullable<Int32> id)
```

Maybe this works...

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your controller extends ApiController rather than Controller

```
 public class CacheManagementController : ApiController
```

rather than

```
 public class CacheManagementController : Controller
```